# Append Tail Node In Linked List With Recursion & No Node Param

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I have the following method

```
    public void insertTailNode(T data) {
        if (this.head == null) {
            Node<T> temp = new Node<T>(data, null);
            this.head = temp;
            this.size++;
        } else if (this.head.getNext() == null) {
            Node<T> temp = new Node<T>(data, this.head);
            this.head = temp;
            this.size++;
        } else {
            this.head = head.getNext();
            insertTailNode(data);
        }
    }
```

Using recursion how can I add a tail node?

I tried using constructors with my head node but that obviously resets back to the first node with every call.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through our decision tree.

- In the first part of your conditional: if there is no head, create a new node and set it as the head.  This makes sense.
- In the second part of your conditional: if the head has nothing after it, create a new node (makes sense) and set it as the head (this does not make sense).  You should not abandon your head node (which has already been set).  If you do, you'll loose the beginning of your list.
- In the last part of your conditional: If here is a head and head has a something after it (the 'else'), move head to the next node (again, this does not make sense) and call the same method.  As before, you should not abandon your head node (which has already been set).

We can genericize your algorithm with a couple of changes.
First, let's pass in a node and call it "currentNode".  So, your method would look like

```
public void insertTailNode(Node< T > currentNode, T data)
```

Second, we'll operate only on the currentNode with the assumption that A) if currentNode is 'null' then you have no head and that B) if the "getNext()" on the current node results in 'null', then it is the tail.

Now, your logic should be

- In the first part of your conditional: if currentNode is 'null', create a new node and set it as the head.
- In the second part of your conditional: if the currentNode has nothing after it, create a new node and set currentNode.next to the new node.
- In the last part of your conditional: If here is a currentNode and the currentNode has a something after it (the 'else'), call the method again like so,

  `insertTailNode( currentNode.getNext(), data );`

Try that and see what happens.

As a note, your first call (to create the head) would be

```
insertTailNode( null, data );
```